# Laravel collection condition in sum

Tags: collections, sum, conditional-statements, laravel-5.7

I have a collection of transactions with relations and I would like to sum column separated by condition of relation column. Right now I have this:

```
    $delegatedProvision = 0;
    $ownProvision = 0;

    foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {
        if ($transaction->discount->consider_improvement) {
            $delegatedProvision += $transaction->stats->$column;
            continue;
        }

        $ownProvision += $transaction->stats->$column;
    }

    $this->salesCollection->put('delegatedProvision', $delegatedProvision);
    $this->salesCollection->put('ownProvision', $ownProvision);
```

It works but I would like to use Laravel collections. So far I have just this:

```
    $provision = $transactions->sum(function ($transaction) use ($column) {
        return $transaction->stats->$column;
    });
```

And I don't know how to use condition in sum() method and according column `$transaction->discount->consider_improvement` (which is boolean) have sum in separated variables. I can use filter each for different `consider_improvement` but it means that I have to iterate all transactions twice.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$collection->where(/* your condition */)->sum($column);
```